Sci-fi TV show about a girl who fights monsters while in a coma
First off, the TV show is introduced by showing a different (Realm) or a (parallel Universe) I do not remember what they called it.
Second, inside this realm there were "monsters" or "beasts" and the protagonist had the power to defeat them only in the realm.
Outside the realm, the protagonist is the daughter of a scientist who is very wealthy who is also in a coma. Now being in a coma is the only way to enter the other realm. The only way to contact her father (who is in a coma) is through text message on a phone. The protagonist is attempting to recruit another male to help them "defeat" her opposition.
The opposition that the protagonist, her father, and her new recruit are attempting to fight off happens to be her father's old partner who is one of the scientist who was able to make the technology to travel to the realm possible. In his work, he had killed his wife, which is what drives him to go into the realm himself to reclaim his wife. 
Towards the end of the series, we find that the man who the protagonist was attempting to recruit had special powers, and he can use those powers to create a bridge (this bridge was made of ice). By crossing this bridge one can cross to the other side, (where the dead are) potentially for this man to bring back his dead wife. As the season ends, we find that this was merely an illusion, and the scientist had potentially created a pathway between these two realms. 
Thank you for any help in remembering this great TV show. I cant believe i haven't remembered the name of it yet. I apologize if  I didn't provide enough information.

by reading the story line .. I am also got interest to watch :D ...

I'm confused.  is the daughter, the father, or both, in a coma?

i'm also confused as to who is fighter the monsters in the coma.  is it the father, daughter, both?  neither?

The show is Beyond 2017

A young man wakes up from a 12 year coma to discover new abilities that come to propel him into the middle of a dangerous conspiracy.




Details largely sourced from TVTropes:
Holden Matthews is the main protagonist, with Willa as the mysterious female who seems to know more about "The Realm", which appears to be a sort of afterlife (although it's implied that's just how people see the illusion of the world) populated by monstrous creatures that appear to everyone but Holden as angelic. Frost is her father, who is trying to find his wife in The Realm. Churchhill is the former partner who serves as the primary antagonist. Holden shows powers of astral projection, precognition, telekinesis and teleportation in the real world. 
Here is the scene where Holden builds The Bridge:



